# Generate with multiple rows data from unique data

Tags: excel

I have a matrix of data in Excel and I want to  with multiple rows data from unique data  like below.  I attach an image of an example of what I need. In the example the data is in A2:B2 , A3:B3 and the unique results will be printed in right side, thank you in advance for the help

[image]

Comment: Going to need a little bit more information here. Is column H just 01/02/03/abc/media repeating? If not, where do those values come from?

Comment: Like you said 01/02/03/abc/media repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining information from 2 input tables to create an output table. Each output row combines information from 2 rows of the input (1 row from each input table) and the output rows are arranged so they loop over the second input table within a loop over the first input table.

The picture shows how to achieve this

[image]

The second table headed `Suffix` is in column `D`.

The ordering of the rows of the output is achieved via columns `J` and `K` and the formulae used will work more generally for any numbers of rows in the two input tables. It is not difficult to extend this approach to cover 3 or more input tables.